# Example of a connected set $X$ such that $\text{int}(X)$ is not

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

My question is: Give an example of a connected set $X$ such that $\text{int}(X)$ is not connected. $X\subset \mathbf{R}$.

I know that every interval is connected, but that is it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=\{x\in \mathbf{R}^2: \lvert x\rvert \le 1\}, B=\{x+(2,0): x\in A\}.$ Basically, we have two circles of radius $r=1$, where one of them is centered at $(0,0)$ and the other is centered at $(2,0)$. Consider $A\cup B$. This set is connected, because it is path connected. However, in this case, $\text{int}(A\cup B)=\text{int}(A)\sqcup \text{int}(B).$ That is, the interior of $A\cup B$ is a set which decomposes into the disjoint union of two open subsets. So, $\text{int}(A\cup B)$ is not connected.

I just noticed that you want your sets to be contained in $\mathbf{R}$. As noted in a comment on my hasty (and incorrect) remark, if you take a connected set in $\mathbf{R}$, then it is necessarily an interval. The interior of an interval is an open interval, which is necessarily connected.

Comment: I don't think any example in $R$ will work. Any connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval,and the interior of an interval is connected.

Comment: Wait, I'm being foolish. Thanks for the remark.